# Timer in python with flask

Tags: python, flask, timer

I am trying to display a timer of 5minutes (for example). I am using flask.
I know it could be good to use javascript but I really want to do it with python.

**I have two issues:**

1. First issue: display of the timer - issue to overwrite

I wrote a function for the timer in python which is supposed to display (for example for 50 seconds):
`00:50` then remove `00:50` and have`00:49`, and so on...
But it is displaying:

```
00:50
00:49
00:48
...
```

Here is my code: `screen.py`

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request, render_template, render_template_string, stream_with_context
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
timing=0
@app.route('/content', methods=['POST', 'GET']) # render the content a url differnt from index. This will be streamed into the iframe
def content():
    global timing
    timing = 10
    # if request.form.get("submit"):
        # timing = request.form['timing']
        # print(timing)
    def countdown(t):
        
        while t:
            mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
            timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
            print(timer, end="\r")
            yield timer
            time.sleep(1)
            t -= 1
        # return timer
        
    return app.response_class(countdown(timing)) #at the moment the time value is hardcoded in the function just for simplicity
    # return render_template('display.html')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    value = "Bonjour"
    title_html = value
    return render_template('display.html', message=title_html) # render a template at the index. The content will be embedded in this template

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=False)
```

I would like to find the equivalence of `print(timer, end="\r")` for `yield` in order to overwrite the value of timer and not see all the results when it's decreasing. I hope my explanation is clear.

2. Second issue: Input value of the timer

As you can see in my code `screen.py`, my value for `timing` is hardcoded `timing=10`. But I would like to allow the user to enter the value he wants in input like that:

```
if request.form.get("submit"):
    timing = request.form['timing']
    print(timing)
```

You can see these lines in `screen.py`, I commented them to leave `timing=10` because when I write these lines I obtain the following error:

```
Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2021 12:50:26] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

Here is the HTML Code linked to my python code `display.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='/static/main.css'/>
    <title>your dish</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{message}}! Here are some informations about your dish:</h1>
    <h2> countdown </h2>
     
    <!-- <p>{{message}}</p> -->
    <form method="POST" action=".">
        <p><input name="timing" value="{{timing}}" placeholder="Enter your time"></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        
    </form>
    <div>
        <iframe frameborder="0" noresize="noresize"
     style='background: transparent; width: 100%; height:100%;' src="{{ url_for('content')}}"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I avoid this error and take into consideration the value entered by the user in the input field of my `display.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tryed to run your script locally but I am not sure where do you expect to see the timer; I assume you used the countdown func from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-using-python/).

I would like to propose you a different approach: stream dynamically the counter to the web page using an iframe:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import time
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/content') # render the content a url differnt from index. This will be streamed into the iframe
def content():
    def timer(t):
        for i in range(t):
            time.sleep(5) #put 60 here if you want to have seconds
            yield str(i)
    return Response(timer(10), mimetype='text/html') #at the moment the time value is hardcoded in the function just for simplicity

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('test.html.jinja') # render a template at the index. The content will be embedded in this template

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=False)
```

then add an iframe where do you prefer in your html

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2> countdown </h2>
    <div>
        <iframe frameborder="0" noresize="noresize"
     style='background: transparent; width: 100%; height:100%;' src="{{ url_for('content')}}"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

The result will be a dynamic countdown on your web-page

**countdown**
0123456789

you can see it done quick and dirty [here on my repl](https://replit.com/@carlo_/timer#main.py)

While it's not tuned around your application yet, (and not particularly beautiful graphically) you can modify the function to accept an input from the user with a form (I see you actually did already in your app), or also tune the countdown function directly.

```
t = request.form['t']
```

and adding to your html the form

```
<form method="post" action=".">
    <p><input name="t" placeholder="your time"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, I edited my question after taking into consideration your changes. Thank you. If you know how to help me with these new issues, feel free!

Comment: yep sure, this one is easy, I guess you just forget to check. 

@app.route('/') miss the POST methods, but you already used that in your app so you should know that. 

It should read:      

@app.route('/', methods = ["GET", "POST"])

if you'd like to see how flask can interact with DOM you can check this example on my github https://github.com/carloocchiena/flask_web_scraper

If you find my answer useful please be so kind to give my answer a +1 :)

Comment: When I add `@app.route('/', methods = ["GET", "POST"])` to `index()`, it's better because I don't get the method error but this page: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/content` is with this error: `Bad Request - The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.` `400 BAD REQUEST`. So the timer is never displayed...

Can you also help me with the first issue please (see the edited question)..thank you!

Comment: I feel like you missed the /templates folder, that would host the display.html file
I run the code on my machine and it worked, but with Flask you have to put all your html files in a /templates folder.

Comment: I put all my HTML files in the /templates folder, I don't understand why it's working for you and not for me. Can you write as an answer the code you have please? Maybe I missed something...

Comment: I checked the code line by line and made some further improvement in logic; most relevant, you have to conver the user input from string to integer.
I feel like i got the result you'd wish: the user input a time value and it is displayed as a countdown on screen.

See the working version on my repl - you'll have the code in the "CODE" tab, near output.

if this helps you please consider accepting my answer\upvoting, thanks!

https://replit.com/@carlo_/timer#main.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235580/discussion-between-carlo-and-camille-bouquet).

Answer (score 0):

You have the same route `@app.route("/")` appearing 3 times. The system will pick the first one which simply displays `display.html`. And I suspect even that will currently not work because your page is expecting values for `message, timing` but those attributes don't exist in your first route.

You should try something like

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def display():
    
    page = 'display.html'
    params = {"message":"", "timing":0} # initialize values for both message and timing. These will be returned when user loads the page (a GET call)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        timing = request.values.get("timing")
        # do whatever processing you want
        params["timing"]  = <your computed value>
        params["message"] = <your message>
        params["message_2"] = <your other message>

    return render_template(page, **params)
```

Delete all the  other routes you have for `@app.route("/")`

Comment: I have done what you said with: `evol_timer = countdown(int(timing))` where countdown(t) is defined without any `@app.route` and then `params["timing"] = request.form['timing']` `params["message"] = "bonjour"` `params["message_2"] = evol_timer`. My issue is my page displays only the number I enter in the input but doesn't display the evolution of the timer, for example for 50 I would like to see 00:50 then 00:49.. but I only see `50`, not even `00:50` ! it should be dynamic but it's not.

Comment: okay. That's a different issue altogether.  One option is to look into Server Side Events (SSE) where you establish a connection to the server and emit the count down values one by one with each value being pushed to the front end. Think of it like instant messaging where each time you type a message (each second of the count down), the message gets pushed to user's screen. But if it were me, I would implement this via Javascript. It seems cleaner and shorter